# Given points $P(0, 3, 0) \;\;\; Q(-3, 4, 2) \;\;\; R(-2, 9, 1) \;$ find the measure of ∠PQR

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, angle

I'm having trouble understanding what this is asking for. I'm able to to see that the dot product between vectors PQ and RP = $0$ and that means those sides form a right triangle, but I don't understand what the question wants me to find and I can't find examples of it anywhere.

Here's what I have so far (bold = vector): 
$$\mathbf a= \mathbf {PQ} \;\;\; and \;\;\; \mathbf c= \mathbf {RP}$$
so
$$\mathbf{a} = \left\langle -3,1,0 \right\rangle \;\;\; and \;\;\; \mathbf{c}=\left\langle 2,-6,-1 \right\rangle$$
now $$\mathbf a \cdot\! \mathbf c=0$$ and that means it is a right triangle, but I'm still stuck at what the question is asking for and even then, since I can't find examples anywhere, I'm not even sure I'll understand how to solve it once I figure what it is aksing for.

If someone can explain what is asking for that would be very helpful, and if you feel comfortable with it, even give a hint on how to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{QP}=P-Q=\langle 3,-1,-2\rangle$ and $\vec{QR}=R-Q=\langle 1,5,-1\rangle$ so $\langle\vec{QP},\vec{QR}\rangle=0$ and so $\angle PQR=\frac{\pi}{2}=90^\circ$.

Comment: Does this mean the way I proved it to be a right triangle is incorrect?

Comment: I thought he was asking for the angle in P!

Comment: Here, let me clarify: If you just look at the title's question, how would you go about answering the question without the other stuff I said. I'm just confused about what to find and how to it.

Comment: @DevHeavy You needed to take the angle between the vectors $\vec{QP}$ and $\vec{QR}$. You took the angle between $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{RP}$. Maybe if you can draw a picture it would be clearer what I mean... $\angle PQR$ has the corner in $Q$.

Comment: @DevHeavy In your derivation you get wrong with the evaluation of vector a

Comment: @gimusi Would you be able to do a step-by-step of proving those points make a right triangle or not and answering the question in the title. I'm getting really confused now and it would be very helpful. OH: I see what you mean, my a is wrong... Let me try again. But still, I'm confused about the question in the title.

Comment: @DevHeavy You basically made two mistakes and they cancelled each other: (1) Calculated the supplement angle to $\angle RPQ$ instead of the requested angle $\angle PQR$; (2) Miscalculated $a$. The final formula is correct, but it was applied to wrong vectors, and one was also not calculated right. Somehow, the result turned out to be right (i.e. zero).

Answer (score 1):

Note that for the **angle in P**

$$\color{red}{\mathbf{a} = \left\langle -3,1,2 \right\rangle} \;\;\; and \;\;\; \mathbf{c}=\left\langle 2,-6,-1 \right\rangle$$

and

$$\cos \theta_P = \frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}}{|\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{c}|}\neq 0$$

Otherwise for the **angle in Q**

$$\mathbf{RQ}={\mathbf{b} = \left\langle -1,-5,1 \right\rangle}$$

and

$$\cos \theta_Q = \frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b}}{|\mathbf{a}||\mathbf{b}|}= 0$$

Thus the triangle is a **right triangle in Q**.

Comment: Ah, I knew that already, just wasn't sure if that is what the question was asking for. Let me try it real quick and get back to you.

Comment: @user8734617 do you think there is a different way I should do this? Does it even matter that it is a triangle made of the three points is a right triangle?

Comment: @DevHeavy they don't seem to be orthogonal, there was a mistake on $\mathbf{a}$

Comment: @gimusi does that mean I messed up? And the triangle isn't a right triangle?

Comment: @user8734617 ok now it is clear, thanks